# Windows Batch Variable within variable with array

Tags: arrays, batch-file, variables

I have the following code:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
call :Retrieve Test
goto eof
:Retrieve <StringVar>
set /a Count_%1=2
```

This results in (in command window with echo on):

```
set /a Count_Test=2
echo !Count_%1!
```

This results in:

```
set "file_%1[!Count_%1!]=*.txt"
```

This results in (in command window with echo on):

```
set "file_Test[!Count_Test!]=*.txt"
```

However, it should be:

```
set "file_Test[2]=*.txt"
set file_%1[
```

Results in:

Environment variable file-Test[ not defined

```
goto eof
:eof
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?!?
Complete code below:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
call :Retrieve Test
goto eof
:Retrieve <StringVar>
set /a Count_%1=2
echo !Count_%1!
set "file_%1[!Count_%1!]=*.txt"
set file_%1[
goto eof
:eof
```

Sorry for my edits, I am new to this...

My question is about the line: `set "file_%1[!Count_%1!]=*.txt"`, the rest of the lines are OK and a sample of my original script.

Comment: My question is about the line: set "file_%1[!Count_%1!]=*.txt", the rest of the lines are OK and a sample of my Original script.

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: Fine... but you know what I mean?

Comment: [Command Prompt and MS-DOS are not the same thing?](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). And please learn [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) first

Comment: Are you aware that command echoing does not resolve delayed expansion, because echoing happens before that?

Comment: Fixed it... If you don't know the answer, why reply? And the others above here? Come on... Is that how you welcome new members?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
set file_%1[
```

Instead of

```
set file-%1[
```

(helps a little if you use the correct variable name)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo... It's not that line that gives a problem.

Comment: Please cut-and-paste code. Retyping introduces tyops.

Comment: Your assertion that he command `echo`ed should be set "file_Test[2]=*.txt" is incorrect. The substitution of a `!var!` cannot be made at parse-time.

Comment: If I test with another var (that's not %1) is works, %test% works like a charm... It must be possible.

Comment: `%test%` can be (indeed is) evaluated at parse-time. The command `echo`ed is the result after parsing. `!var!`s are evaluated at run-time, after parsing. Or are you asserting that with `test` set to `2`, `set "file_%test%[!Count_%test%!]=*.txt"`yields a `echo`ed report other than  `set "file_2[!Count_2!]=*.txt"` ?

Comment: I don't want it to echo... I want it to set: set "file_Test[2]=*.txt"

Comment: The original code does precisely that. Simply add a `set file` command on the line after after  the `call :retrieve` and it will display all of the variables named starting with `file`.

Comment: No, the echo was for testing purposes, I have found it myself... I remembered a trick I used before. Tnx anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it already...

```
call set "file_%1[!Count_%1!]=*.txt"
```

Did the trick...